# How to get selected attributes of an object in to a python list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, python-2.x

How do I create a list with the selected attributes of an object in python ? Using list comprehensions.

E.g:

My object A has

```
A.name
A.age
A.height
```

and many more attributes

How do I create a list `[name,age]`

I can do it manually but it looks ugly:

```
l=[]
l.append(A.name)
l.append(A.age)
```

but I am looking for a shortcut.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by using list comprehensions here, you don't need (and can't really use) a comprehension for what you describe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just `[A.name, A.age]`? `list` literals are simple. [You could use `operator.attrgetter` if you need to do it a lot](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter), though it returns `tuple`s when fetching multiple attributes, not `list`s, so you'd have to convert if you can't live with that.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter)

```
attrs = ['name', 'age'] 
l = list(operator.attrgetter(*attrs)(A))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect them going through all `A` class attributes and checking if they aren't method or built-in.

```
import inspect

def collect_props():
    for name in dir(A):
        if not inspect.ismethod(getattr(A, name)) and\
           not name.startswith('__'):
            yield name

print list(collect_props())
```